# How to retrieve output of external program executed from Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

I want to run an external program from Haskell and retrieve the contents of its output and error streams. In one of the libraries I found this code:

```
runProcess :: FilePath -> [String] -> IO (ExitCode, String, String)
runProcess prog args = do
  (_,o,e,p) <- runInteractiveProcess prog args Nothing Nothing
  hSetBuffering o NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering e NoBuffering
  sout  <- hGetContents o
  serr  <- hGetContents e
  ecode <- length sout `seq` waitForProcess p
  return (ecode, sout, serr)
```

Is this the right way to do it?

There are some things I don't understand here: why streams are set to `NoBuffering`? Why `` length sout `seq` ``? This feels like some kind of hack.

Also, I would like to merge output and error streams into one to get the same effect as if I did `2>&1` on the command line. If possible, I want to avoid using dedicated I/O libraries and rely on standard packages provided with GHC.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get the same effect as if you do `2>&1` in the shell. Is there any particular reason you would want that?

Comment: I'd say the reason for `seq` is to force consuming the complete output of the program. Otherwise (since the strings are lazy) a deadlock could happen: the sub-process would be waiting on writing its output and the master process waiting for the process to finish. But it seems there could be the same problem with `serr`, I'd be worried that if the program wrote a lot of output to its stderr, the above code could hang as well. Doing this right probably won't be very simple, so I'd perhaps rather look for some stable IO library that solves the problem already.

Comment: Also do you need the program to be multi-platform, or are you targeting a specific platform?

Comment: The `process` library has the function `readProcessWithExitCode` that returns both `stdout` and `stderr` as strings. If the process writes a lot of output, if you want to have access to the output while the program is running, or if you want `stdout` and `stderr` to be interleaved, this won't be enough though.

Comment: I want my code to be portable across platform. I can leave without `2>&1`. Also, I will be happy with redirecting output and error streams to files on the disk.

Comment: If you use `runProcess` and pass in the same handle for stdout and stderr (instead of `Nothing`), it should work like `2>&1`.

Answer (score 4):

Use Shelly, a module for shell-like programming in Haskell:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly-1.4.1/docs/Shelly.html

Answer (score 4):

This example program uses the `process`, `async`, `pipes`, and `pipes-bytestring` packages to execute an external command and write `stdout` and `stderr` to separate files while the command runs:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Exception
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as P
import Pipes.Concurrent
import System.Process
import System.IO

writeToFile :: Handle -> FilePath -> IO ()
writeToFile handle path = 
    finally (withFile path WriteMode $ \hOut ->
                runEffect $ P.fromHandle handle >-> P.toHandle hOut)
            (hClose handle) 

main :: IO ()
main = do
   (_,mOut,mErr,procHandle) <- createProcess $ 
        (proc "foo" ["--help"]) { std_out = CreatePipe
                                , std_err = CreatePipe 
                                }
   let (hOut,hErr) = maybe (error "bogus handles") 
                           id
                           ((,) <$> mOut <*> mErr)
   a1 <- async $ writeToFile hOut "stdout.txt" 
   a2 <- async $ writeToFile hErr "stderr.txt" 
   waitBoth a1 a2
   return ()
```

And this is a variation that writes `stdout` and `stderr` interleaved to the same file:

```
writeToMailbox :: Handle -> Output ByteString -> IO ()
writeToMailbox handle oMailbox = 
     finally (runEffect $ P.fromHandle handle >-> toOutput oMailbox)
             (hClose handle) 

writeToFile :: Input ByteString -> FilePath -> IO ()
writeToFile iMailbox path = 
    withFile path WriteMode $ \hOut ->
         runEffect $ fromInput iMailbox >-> P.toHandle hOut

main :: IO ()
main = do
   (_,mOut,mErr,procHandle) <- createProcess $ 
        (proc "foo" ["--help"]) { std_out = CreatePipe
                                , std_err = CreatePipe 
                                }
   let (hOut,hErr) = maybe (error "bogus handles") 
                           id
                           ((,) <$> mOut <*> mErr)
   (mailBoxOut,mailBoxIn,seal) <- spawn' Unbounded
   a1 <- async $ writeToMailbox hOut mailBoxOut 
   a2 <- async $ writeToMailbox hErr mailBoxOut 
   a3 <- async $ waitBoth a1 a2 >> atomically seal 
   writeToFile mailBoxIn "combined.txt" 
   wait a3
   return ()
```

It uses `pipes-concurrent`. The threads that drain each handle write to the same mailbox. The mailbox is read by the main thread, which writes the output file while the command runs.

Answer (score 3):

I find [`readProcessWithExitCode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.8.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcessWithExitCode) for this purpose very succinct.

Here's an example using only functions from GHC's standard libraries. The program lists the files of your home directory sorted by size, printing the process' exit code as well as the contents of the standard out and standard error streams:

```
import           System.Directory               ( getHomeDirectory )
import           System.Process                 ( readProcessWithExitCode )
import           System.Exit                    ( ExitCode )
import           Data.List.NonEmpty

callCmd :: NonEmpty String -> IO (ExitCode, String, String)
callCmd (cmd :| args) = readProcessWithExitCode cmd args stdIn
  where stdIn = ""

main = do
  home                       <- getHomeDirectory
  (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) <-
    callCmd $ "ls" :| [home, "--almost-all", "-l", "-S"]
  putStrLn
    $  "Exit code: "
    ++ show exitCode
    ++ "\nOut: "
    ++ stdOut
    ++ "\nErr: "
    ++ stdErr
```

Comment: Is the `:|` an operator in `callCmd (cmd :| args) = readProcessWithExitCode cmd args stdIn where stdIn = ""`? If so, which one? To my knowledge, `:` is the list append operator, but what about the `|`? And it is also used by the caller in `callCmd $ "ls" :| [home, "--almost-all", "-l", "-S"]`. So it is creating a list of arguments, but why and when is it needed (is this shorthand like `callCmd $`? Maybe it would help to know how to read this `(cmd :| args)` notation in Plain English. Nicely done by the way.

Comment: `:|` is the constructor for creating a [non-empty list](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html). In `callCmd (cmd :| args)` it's used as a deconstructor to get the first element (`cmd`) of the non-empty list and the rest of the list, `args`.