# How to know what are the full list of function availlable in an import?

Tags: list, haskell

In Haskell if I import a module e.g.

```
import Data.List
```

How can I know what is the total method that Data.List made available ?

In Prelude I can use completion like said here [Is there a way to see the list of functions in a module, in GHCI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698942/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-list-of-functions-in-a-module-in-ghci)::

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> Data.List.<PRESS TAB KEY HERE>
```

But I want to get this in a list that be can manipulate, not in Prelude.

This question is not about builtins [how to know in Haskell the builtins functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463573/how-to-know-in-haskell-the-builtins-functions), (I mean by builtins available functions we have without doing any import)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to know in Haskell the builtins functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463573/how-to-know-in-haskell-the-builtins-functions)

Comment: What do you mean "not in Prelude"? Do you mean not in GHCi?

Comment: To access the imports of a module as any sort of Haskell data structure, you must use the GHC API (See [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.2.1/index.html) for latest version of the docs for the GHC API, which may differ significantly from whatever version you are using). This is a fairly involved and complicated process, and there may be a much simpler way of accomplishing whatever you are trying to accomplish (but you haven't stated what that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your Haskell program you can call [*ghc-mod*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod). It is a standalone program that is able to do what you want:

eg in the terminal the command  `ghc-mod browse Data.List` returns

```
all
and
any
break
concat
concatMap
cycle
...
```

If you need the types of the functions you can use `ghc-mod browse -d Data.List`. It returns:

```
all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]
concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]
cycle :: [a] -> [a]
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
...
```

You can install *ghc-mod* with *cabal*. To call *ghc-mod* from your Haskell program, you can [follow the answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464639/how-to-retrieve-output-of-external-program-executed-from-haskell). The preferred waŷ is to use the *shelly* library.

Here is a small demo program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Shelly
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = shelly $ silently $ do
    out <- run "ghc-mod" ["browse", "-d", "Data.List"] 
    -- lns will containes a list of lines with the function names and their types
    let lns = T.lines out
    -- Here we print out the number of functions and the first 5 functions
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ show $ Prelude.length lns
    liftIO $ mapM_ (putStrLn .T.unpack) $ take 5 lns
```

Comment: At the moment you cannot install _ghc-mod_ with GHC 8.0.1 or 8.2.1. However It installes smoothly with GHC 8.0.2.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but `ghc-mod` deprecated for `haskell-ide-engine` deprecated for `haskell-language-server`

Answer (score 11):

You can use browse:

```
Prelude> :browse Data.List
```

It will list all the methods available

Answer (score 2):

There is online documentation available, for example [here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.0/base-4.9.1.0/Data-List.html). It is generally best practice to use qualified imports like `import qualified Data.List as L` or `import Data.List (permutations, foldl')` to avoid this issue, though.